How create interactive infographics and flowchart with motion?
I want to create attractive infographics or flowchart similar below image?
Could introduce me software , tools, AI, Online websites for doing that?
do these created by video makers or creators?
Do these gif images created by video makers software?
Are these software free?


Javascript is recommended in the answer since this a programming forum. You can create what you showed using JS in the browser anyway. Try something and we will help you.

You can create animated diagram by Canva,draw.io or Figma.

You can use JavaScript code alone instead of needing software.
Research:

Pixel programming for Canvas.
About using JS keyframes.
About recording video of Canvas

As a starting point, you can do this with FlowChart JS.
Here is a simple code example:
https://code.balkan.app/flowchart-js/attractive-flowchart#JS
Also for vector shapes SVG animation (using timeline, etc) you can try the free tool: https://www.svgator.com/vector-animation-software

I liked you answer but i think  should be easer.
